# Batch rename multiple numbers in filename with different padding

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename, batch-rename, renaming

I am trying to rename a batch of files of the form:

```
test1_run1
test1_run2
   ...
test1_run10
  ...
test10_run1
test10_run2
  ...
test10_run10
```

to the form with multiple paddings. For the first number I need padding with zeros of length 5 and for the second with length 3.

The final result should be of the form:

```
test00001_run001
test00001_run002
  ...
test00001_run010
  ...
test00010_run001
test00010_run002
  ...
test00010_run010
```

How can I do this in bash for all the files in a particular folder?

Comment: There are multiple tags for "renaming". I suggested merging [rename] and [renaming] and you can vote (up or down) in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rename/synonyms

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

for file in test+([[:digit:]])_run+([[:digit:]]); do
    [[ $file =~ ^test([[:digit:]]+)_run([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]
    printf -v newfile 'test_%05d_run%03d' "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}))" "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]}))"
    echo mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Run this from within the folder you want to process. This will only `echo` the `mv` commands to be performed. Remove the `echo` if you're happy with the result.

- we're using the shell option `nullglob` so that non-matching globs expand to nothing;
- we're using the shell option `extglob` because the `for` loop will use extended globs;
- the extended glob `test+([[:digit:]])_run+([[:digit:]])` will expand to the files matching this pattern (if any)
- we're using a regex to get the digits from the file names; the first number will be in `BASH_REMATCH[1]` and the second in `BASH_REMATCH[2]`.
- we're using `printf` to format the new file name; the modifiers `%05d` and `%03d` will format the numbers according to your wishes (with appropriate leading zeroes). Observe that we're using `((10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}))` to explicitly specify that the number is in radix 10, in case you have a file `test09_run001`. The `09` part would make bash misinterpret the number in radix 8 (because of the leading 0) and you'll get a complaint; the `-v` switch tells `printf` to not output on standard output, but to store the output in variable `newfile`;
- finally we perform the `mv`.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the string into `test` + `5 digits` + `_run` + `3 digits` formats by saying:

```
$ awk -F"test" '{split($2,a,"_run"); printf "%s%0.5d%s%0.3d\n", FS, a[1], "_run", a[2]}' a
test00001_run001
test00001_run002
test00001_run010
test00010_run001
test00010_run002
test00010_run010
```

This works by using `test` as field separator and splitting the 2nd field in two parts: before and after `_run`. Then, it uses the `printf` thingies to get the proper output.

Then, you can print `mv` together with the previous value and say:

```
$ awk -F"test" '{split($2,a,"_run"); printf "mv %s %s%0.5d%s%0.3d\n", $0, FS, a[1], "_run", a[2]}' a
mv test1_run1 test00001_run001
mv test1_run2 test00001_run002
mv test1_run10 test00001_run010
mv test10_run1 test00010_run001
mv test10_run2 test00010_run002
mv test10_run10 test00010_run010
```

If you then pipe it to `sh`, it will get executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use perl or awk, and strictly use bash and some utility programs that are available in most distribution, you can try something like this:

```
for i in * ; do
    testpart=`echo $i | cut -d_ -f1`
    testnum=${testpart#test}
    runpart=`echo $i | cut -d_ -f2`
    runnum=${runpart#run}
    destfile=test`printf %05d $testnum`_run`printf %03d $runnum`

    mv $i $destfile
done
```